# getting permission denied on app engine deploy

Tags: go

cannot run gcloud app deploy i get the following on terminal  (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 8c84eb5e-f6b7-4170-a87d-80754fecfbbe status: FAILURE
removing /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath: unlinkat /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath/pkg/mod/gonum.org/v1/gonum@v0.9.3/internal/math32/signbit.go: permission denied
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/8c84eb5e-f6b7-4170-a87d-80754fecfbbe?project=552359020884

```
starting build "f0da5db4-4130-4784-9276-90236bc2e6c6"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetch"
Step #0 - "fetch": Pulling image: us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": base_20220302a_18_04_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetch": 05867982f162: Pulling fs layer
Step #0 - "fetch": 05867982f162: Verifying Checksum
Step #0 - "fetch": 05867982f162: Download complete
Step #0 - "fetch": 05867982f162: Pull complete
Step #0 - "fetch": Digest: sha256:3534f59733f91a6b570e0fee8394f356100459ce1b9b25aa80fa0dae19fd2b4b
Step #0 - "fetch": Status: Downloaded newer image for us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": Fetching manifest gs://staging.fitstack-343223.appspot.com/ae/b92b526e-7dcf-4786-9d01-988286bbd036/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetch": Processing 32 files.
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetch": Status:                      SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetch": Started:                     2022-03-16T01:27:57Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Completed:                   2022-03-16T01:27:57Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Requested workers:    200
Step #0 - "fetch": Actual workers:        32
Step #0 - "fetch": Total files:           32
Step #0 - "fetch": Total retries:          0
Step #0 - "fetch": GCS timeouts:           0
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB downloaded:         0.27 MiB
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB/s throughput:       2.30 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetch": Time for manifest:     73.99 ms
Step #0 - "fetch": Total time:             0.20 s
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetch"
Starting Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Pulling image: us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": base_20220302a_18_04_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 47d17572643b: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": b69d4a399026: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5683da2e62ee: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5d61b34c58e5: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 871c5c6098f7: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 258748e39430: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9044308efa14: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 3dcf4435d2c6: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": dc5b391f6f2a: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2c067104188b: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e60795ed0a63: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": b8988709d36f: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": ab002007ac6d: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": b8988709d36f: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": ab002007ac6d: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e60795ed0a63: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e60795ed0a63: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e60795ed0a63: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": b8988709d36f: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": ab002007ac6d: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Digest: sha256:275cba4037e38f32445232017e902e70e6b29251ddbf8e2fba1b95f3fe37a6cf
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Status: Downloaded newer image for us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/utilities/buildpack-shim:base_20220302a_18_04_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /layers
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /workspace
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/home
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/outputs
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /platform/env
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable BUILDER_OUTPUT to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_DEBUG to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_VERSION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_RUN_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GAE_APP_ENGINE_APIS to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_EXPERIMENTAL_AR_AUTH_ENABLED to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Retagging us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest as us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:f0da5db4-4130-4784-9276-90236bc2e6c6
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Checking if image us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Image us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest"(us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 381.418627ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Checking if image us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest is valid
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: ...pull("us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest") took 95.856602ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: ...validate("us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest") took 204.495818ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Image us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest is valid
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest"(us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 300.520902ms
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Image us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest copied to us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:f0da5db4-4130-4784-9276-90236bc2e6c6
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": DEBUG: "us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest", "us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:f0da5db4-4130-4784-9276-90236bc2e6c6"(us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest) took 634.021045ms
Finished Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Starting Step #2 - "build"
Step #2 - "build": Pulling image: us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/go116/builder:go116_20220306_1_16_13_RC00
Step #2 - "build": go116_20220306_1_16_13_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/buildpacks/go116/builder
Step #2 - "build": 47d17572643b: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": b69d4a399026: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 5683da2e62ee: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 5d61b34c58e5: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 871c5c6098f7: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 258748e39430: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 9044308efa14: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 3dcf4435d2c6: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": dc5b391f6f2a: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 2c067104188b: Already exists
Step #2 - "build": 0f543a8b6413: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 6b10d361d16a: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 11c1bcc7b79a: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": d41faa8feb5c: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 49ef2925f143: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 9ebd49cad864: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 9f660d20a3a2: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": e8c7adea3b75: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": bfddb12fd793: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 2dc944e4043e: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 674804e5a494: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": fe55734633e1: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": d1ced7a31646: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 8d51793b1c23: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": d32271d57ef0: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 50e8b9c0dddc: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
Step #2 - "build": d41faa8feb5c: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 49ef2925f143: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 674804e5a494: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 9ebd49cad864: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": fe55734633e1: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 9f660d20a3a2: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": e8c7adea3b75: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": d1ced7a31646: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 8d51793b1c23: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": d32271d57ef0: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": bfddb12fd793: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 2dc944e4043e: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 50e8b9c0dddc: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Waiting
Step #2 - "build": 6b10d361d16a: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 6b10d361d16a: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 0f543a8b6413: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 0f543a8b6413: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": d41faa8feb5c: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": d41faa8feb5c: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 49ef2925f143: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 0f543a8b6413: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 9ebd49cad864: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 9ebd49cad864: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 9f660d20a3a2: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 9f660d20a3a2: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": e8c7adea3b75: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": e8c7adea3b75: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 6b10d361d16a: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": bfddb12fd793: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": bfddb12fd793: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 2dc944e4043e: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 2dc944e4043e: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 674804e5a494: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 674804e5a494: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": fe55734633e1: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": fe55734633e1: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": d1ced7a31646: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": d1ced7a31646: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": d32271d57ef0: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": d32271d57ef0: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 8d51793b1c23: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 8d51793b1c23: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 50e8b9c0dddc: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 50e8b9c0dddc: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 11c1bcc7b79a: Verifying Checksum
Step #2 - "build": 11c1bcc7b79a: Download complete
Step #2 - "build": 11c1bcc7b79a: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": d41faa8feb5c: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 49ef2925f143: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 9ebd49cad864: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 9f660d20a3a2: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": e8c7adea3b75: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 06f428a8446f: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": dcaad5a887e8: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": bfddb12fd793: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 2dc944e4043e: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 674804e5a494: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": fe55734633e1: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": d1ced7a31646: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 8d51793b1c23: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": d32271d57ef0: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 50e8b9c0dddc: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": 4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Step #2 - "build": Digest: sha256:874ed274d98a67c23a1102811baac2313a3db7b0e1d60f2bdc34c9e2615e45a7
Step #2 - "build": Status: Downloaded newer image for us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/go116/builder:go116_20220306_1_16_13_RC00
Step #2 - "build": us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/go116/builder:go116_20220306_1_16_13_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ===> DETECTING
Step #2 - "build": google.go.appengine_gomod 0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.go.gomod           0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.go.build           0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.go.appengine       0.9.0
Step #2 - "build": google.utils.label        0.0.2
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": Previous image with name "us.gcr.io/fitstack-343223/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:b92b526e-7dcf-4786-9d01-988286bbd036" not found
Step #2 - "build": Restoring metadata for "google.go.gomod:gopath" from cache
Step #2 - "build": ===> RESTORING
Step #2 - "build": Restoring data for "google.go.gomod:gopath" from cache
Step #2 - "build": ===> BUILDING
Step #2 - "build": === App Engine Gomod (google.go.appengine_gomod@0.9.0) ===
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "cp --dereference -R . /layers/google.go.appengine_gomod/srv"
Step #2 - "build": Done "cp --dereference -R . /layers/google.go.appengine_gomod/srv" (62.041821ms)
Step #2 - "build": === Go - Gomod (google.go.gomod@0.9.0) ===
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: go.mod SHA has changed: clearing GOPATH layer's cache
Step #2 - "build": Failure: (ID: 4516fb13) removing /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath: unlinkat /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath/pkg/mod/gonum.org/v1/gonum@v0.9.3/internal/math32/signbit.go: permission denied
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/outputs/output"
Step #2 - "build": Done "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/o..." (35.537571ms)
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/go116/builder:go116_20220306_1_16_13_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 145
```

here is my go mod

```
module github.com/voodoostack/fitstackapi

go 1.17

require golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220214200702-86341886e292

require (
    github.com/99designs/gqlgen v0.17.1
    github.com/georgysavva/scany v0.3.0
    github.com/go-chi/chi v1.5.4
    github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4 v4.15.1
    github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 v4.15.0
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.4.0
    github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx v1.2.20
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.7.0
    github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2 v2.4.0
)

require (
    github.com/agnivade/levenshtein v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/v2 v2.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/decred/dcrd/dcrec/secp256k1/v4 v4.0.0-20210816181553-5444fa50b93d // indirect
    github.com/goccy/go-json v0.9.4 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/errwrap v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/chunkreader/v2 v2.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgconn v1.11.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgio v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgpassfile v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgproto3/v2 v2.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgservicefile v0.0.0-20200714003250-2b9c44734f2b // indirect
    github.com/jackc/pgtype v1.10.0 // indirect
    github.com/jackc/puddle v1.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/backoff/v2 v2.0.8 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/blackmagic v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/httpcc v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/iter v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/option v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.2 // indirect
    github.com/matryer/moq v0.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/russross/blackfriday/v2 v2.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/stretchr/objx v0.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/urfave/cli/v2 v2.3.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/atomic v1.6.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.5.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20211019181941-9d821ace8654 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.1.9 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c // indirect
)
```

and finally my app.yaml

```
runtime: go117
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
  - url: .*
    script: auto
env_variables:
  DATABASE_URL: none
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
network: {}
service_account: fitstack-343223@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud with the appengine doesn't support go 1.17 yet, only go 1.16 max at the moment